# Can't find config.php file on docker nextcloud

Tags: docker, nextcloud

I just installed nextcloud via Docker but I don't know how to connect to my nextcloud server from other computers.
After googling I learned that I have to edit my
/var/www/nextcloud/config.php
file but I can't find it. is there any way that I can find my config.php file so that I can do port forwarding setting?
Thank you.

Comment: have u tried `find /var -name "config.php"`?

Answer (score 0):

For this volume

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:apache
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
```

And nextcloud version `23.0.3`, the config file is in

```
root@74f48cf77ccc:~# find /var -name "config.php"
/var/www/html/config/config.php
```